# Serverless database setup with dependecy injection

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typeorm

So, I'm working on a serverless lambda with express and TypeORM

I'm having issues to instance the database and then use it in the repository class to retreive data.

```
// handler.ts
require('source-map-support/register');
import App from './features/app';
import LeadsController from './features/leads/leads.controller';
import { Container } from 'typedi';

import 'source-map-support/register';
import serverlessExpress from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { Context } from 'aws-lambda';

const setup = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  const app = new App([Container.get(LeadsController)], 3000);
  await app.init();
  return serverlessExpress({ app: app.app })(event, context, () => {
    console.log('callback');
  });
};

const handler = (event: any, context: Context) => {
  return setup(event, context);
};

exports.handler = handler;
```

```
// app.ts
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Database } from '../common/database/db';

class App {
  public app: express.Application;
  public port: number;

  constructor(controllers: any[], port: number) {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = port;
    this.initializeMiddlewares();
    this.initializeControllers(controllers);
    this.endMiddlewares();
  }

  async init() {
    const database = new Database(); // HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS, I CAN'T FIND ANOTHER WAY TO INIT THE DATABASE
    await database.connect();
  }
  private initializeMiddlewares() {
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
  }

  private initializeControllers(controllers: any[]) {
    const router: Router[] = [];
    controllers.forEach((controller) => {
      router.push(controller.router);
    });
    this.app.use('/api', router);
  }

  private endMiddlewares() {
    // @todo: set up error handler;
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
// repository.ts
import { Service } from 'typedi';
import { Database } from '../../common/database/db';
import { Lead } from './leads.entity';

@Service()
export class LeadsRepository {
  private repository;
  constructor(private readonly db: Database) {
    console.log(db); // AND HERE IS MY OTHER PROBLEM
    this.repository = this.db.dataSource.getRepository(Lead);
  }

  async findAll() {
    return await this.repository.find();
  }
}
```

```
// db.ts
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { Lead } from '../../features/leads/leads.entity';
import { Interest } from '../../features/interests/interests.entity';
import { MysqlConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlConnectionOptions';
import { Service } from 'typedi';

/**
 * Database manager class
 */
@Service()
export class Database {
  dataSource: DataSource;

  constructor() {}

  async connect() {
    const connectionOptions: MysqlConnectionOptions = {
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 33061,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'leads-interests',
      synchronize: true,
      dropSchema: true,
      logging: 'all',
      entities: [Lead, Interest],
      subscribers: [],
      migrations: [__dirname + '/migration.{ts,js}'],
      migrationsTableName: '_migration'
    };
    this.dataSource = new DataSource(connectionOptions);
    await this.dataSource.initialize();
    console.log('Connected');
  }
}
```

After a lot of thinking and learning about dependency injection I reached the conclusion that my problem is where I instance the database in the first place, but tbh I don't know where else should I do it since it's an async call and I don't wanna be creating new instance everytime I have to retreive or insert data.

Does anyone have another workaround or a better code architecture that I can use?

In the end, what I need is to always use the same database instance

Answer (score 1):

I see that the app constructor has controllers(which in turn depends on the repository and then database?)  in its dependencies and before the database connection function can complete its task the controller has already been resolved from the container.

To resolve this, try instantiating the database first in the setup function and explicitly set the database in the container like so:

```
const setup = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  const database = new Database();
  await database.connect();
  Container.set(Database,database); //import Container from 'typedi'
  const app = new App([Container.get(LeadsController)], 3000);
  await app.init();
  return serverlessExpress({ app: app.app })(event, context, () => {
    console.log('callback');
  });
};
```

Or even better, initialize the datasource on setup function and create a custom identifier for it and inject datasource using the injection token in your repository.

In general though, I would not recommend performing Dependency Injection on serverless functions because it will increase the cold start times and you should try to optimize your application startup time in a serverless environment.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I thought the same about the performance, but in that case how would I keep me connection to the database alive? Should I just use a new connection every time because of serverless? If the answer is yes my problems are almost solved I wouldn’t use DI and it’s done. At the end I realize that DI is running before the actual instance creation of the Database and that was triggering the issue

Comment: You will need to store the connection on a global variable and in your setup function check if that global variable will be assigned with the connection on the first run. on your setup function you will only connect to the database it its null. and after successful connection you will store the connection on to the variable.  I am not sure how effective  that is since I don't know much about the lifetime of a lambda function, check the docs!

Comment: In case you're wondering, using DI alone will not keep the connection alive since the setup function runs on every invocation and it will connect to the database on every request.

Comment: Mhm, I thought the same about the global. I will try that.